# How to control permissions on external USB hard disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, permissions, rsync

I'm using RHEL 6.5, andhave an auto-mounted external USB drive.  Any and all files created in the mounted filesystem are given permission 700 for dirs and 777 for files.  The chmod command does not change the permissions.

I want to use rsync to backup my files to the drive, but I don't want to lose my permission settings. My trial runs with "rsync -avh" preserve the time stamps and the user and group settings, but not permissions.

Where are these being controlled for such a drive, and how can I turn off this forced setting?

Comment: What Filesystem is being used on the drive ? and what mount options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the filesystem you are using on your external drive. Since you have mentioned that permission changing operations do not work, it is likely you have either NTFS or FAT32.

Since you want to make a backup, the best way to do that to different file-system would be to make an archive with a tool like `tar` or similar. They have command switches for preserving permissions etc.

Regarding permissions of NTFS/FAT32 filesystems: while you can't control permissions of individual files or directories, you can specify permission which will be used when mounting the drive using `dmask`, `fmask` and `umask` options:

- `uid` set the owner user of all files
- `gid` set the owner group of all files
- `dmask` controls permissions for directories
- `fmask` controls permissions for files
- `umask` controls the bitmask of the permissions that are not present (defaults to the umask of current process)

These can be either put into `/etc/fstab` or just added to `mount` command as `-o` arguments:

```
$ mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

If you want to put it in `/etc/fstab` instead, you have to put them under `options` (4th column):

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
/dev/sdXY    /mnt    ntfs   uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137    0     0
```

Comment: Curses, it is indeed NTFS.  I should have known to format it to ext4 first. But thanks for the help with the mount options. Those will be useful!